# In Mac OS, how to always HIDE toolbar in fullscreen mode?

Tags: macos, mac

Google results for this question are entirely polluted by answers about how to check or uncheck *always SHOW* the menu/toolbar in fullscreen mode, but there is zero information about how to always HIDE the menu/toolbar in fullscreen mode.

Context: When using Chrome Remote Desktop it's usually preferable to use it in full screen mode. When I move my mouse up towards the top of the screen to select something from another app I use full screen (e.g. clicking a tab, on a browser), it forces focus away from Chrome Remote Desktop and back into Mac OS by dropping the toolbar. And then it steals my click or forces me to waste time repositioning the cursor and waiting for it to go away.

I have tried the "always show" option but there are two drawbacks:

1. (not a dealbreaker): It reduces the screen size and forces you to always use the "full screen" application at less than full screen.
2. Dealbreaker: There is STILL a dropdown that covers up all the browser tabs. It's just not the menu/toolbar anymore, but rather a gray bar from the Mac UI which includes the option to close or expand the window.

Bonus question: Shouldn't this be a very common use case for full screen apps? No other OS I've ever used, including Windows, has ever had this issue. Does anyone know *why* Apple designed it in such an annoying way without simply adding the option to always hide the toolbar?